# Convert a simple one line string to RDD in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, distributed-computing, rdd

I have a simple line:

```
line = "Hello, world"
```

I would like to convert it to an RDD with only one element. 
I have tried

```
sc.parallelize(line)
```

But it get:

```
sc.parallelize(line).collect()
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

try using List as parameter:

```
sc.parallelize(List(line)).collect()
```

it returns

```
res1: Array[String] = Array(hello,world)
```

Comment: Actually, using sc.parallelize([line]).collect() worked.

Comment: in my env （ scala 2.10.3 spark-1.0.0 ) sc.parallelize([line]).collect() doesn't work

Comment: I forgot to specify that I am using the python api.

Comment: @michaeltang @poiuytrez Is this still the way to do it with `pyspark 3.0.0`

Answer (score 1):

The below code works fine in Python

```
sc.parallelize([line]).collect()
['Hello, world']
```

Here we are passing the parameter "line" as a list.

Comment: Is this still the way to do it with pyspark 3.0.0

Answer (score 0):

use the following code :

```
sc.parallelize(Seq(line))
```

Comment: it would be nicer if you add some explanation to your answer