# Python - Map with Split Option output Difference

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, split

I'm a newbie to python just trying to understand why the output is like this.

1)

```
strr=['asdfasdf','asdf','sdf','sdf']

stak=map(lambda l:l.split(','),strr)

print(stak)
```

When i execute the first set, the output would be of the format as below which is understandable 
because, the split returns a list and the collect as well returns a list and hence the lists inside 
the list

```
[['asdfasdf'], ['asdf'], ['sdf'], ['sdf']]
```

2)

```
str='asdfasdf,asdf,sdf,sdf'

sc.parallelize(str).map(lambda l:l.split(',')).collect()

print(str)
```

Now check the 2nd case, the below action should have also done the same as above and should have 
given the similar output. But instead its giving the output as below. What i don't get it, why has 
the characters been separated into separate lists. Could anyone please explain why difference in 
outputs in 1 and 2?

```
[['a'],
 ['s'],
 ['d'],
 ['f'],
 ['a'],
 ['s'],
 ['d'],
 ['f'],
 ['', ''],
 ['a'],
 ['s'],
 ['d'],
 ['f'],
 ['', ''],
 ['s'],
 ['d'],
 ['f'],
 ['', ''],
 ['s'],
 ['d'],
 ['f']]
```

Comment: "sc.parallelize" seems to be part of an external library. You should add the appropriate tag to the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. `split` returns `list` in Python, since no element in the list has `comma (,)`, it returns list for every value with only one element **value itself** as you are mapping split to every element in the list. The output is **list of lists**.
2. Since you are using parallelize on string, it breaks the string into RDD of characters and then map split on every character, which again returns you list of lists as explained in #1. Only when it encounters comma as character you get list with two empty strings and it gets splitted.
   for more info [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157620/convert-a-simple-one-line-string-to-rdd-in-spark)